# Seemingly inconsistent borrow-checker behaviour in loops

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

While testing an implementation of a rudimentary plug-in system, I ran into some seemingly inconsistent borrow-checker behaviour.

With the following structures

```
struct Plugin {
    data: [u8; 256],
}

impl Plugin {
    fn new() -> Plugin { Plugin { data: [0; 256], } }
    fn write(&mut self, port: usize, val: u8) { self.data[port] = val; }
    fn read(&self, port: usize) -> u8 { self.data[port] }
}

struct System<'a> {
    plugin: Option<&'a mut Plugin>,
}

impl<'a> System<'a> {
    fn new() -> System<'a> { System { plugin: None, } }
    fn attach_plugin(&mut self, plugin: &'a mut Plugin) { self.plugin = Some(plugin); }
    fn detach_plugin(&mut self) { self.plugin = None; }
}
```

Given the following setup code

```
let mut system = System::new();
let mut plugin = Plugin::new();

system.attach_plugin(&mut plugin);
```

The following code doesn't work

```
for i in 0..255 {
    system.plugin.as_mut().unwrap().write(i as usize, i);
    let val = plugin.data[i as usize]; // This line produces two errors
    assert_eq!(val, i);
}
```

Showing these two error messages:

> `error[E0503]: cannot use 'plugin.data' because it was mutably borrowed`

and

> `error[E0503]: cannot use 'plugin.data[_]' because it was mutably borrowed`

However, if the access through the System is separated out into it's own loop the code compiles with no errors or warnings.

```
for i in 0..255 {
    system.plugin.as_mut().unwrap().write(i as usize, i);
}
for i in 0..255 {
    let val = plugin.data[i as usize]; // This line doesn't produce any errors
    assert_eq!(val, i);
}
```

The only notable difference that I noticed between the two examples is that in the working example the first line is in its own scope, but making the following changes to the error-producing code doesn't fix the errors:

```
for i in 0..255 {
    {
        system.plugin.as_mut().unwrap().write(i as usize, i);
    }
    let val = plugin.data[i as usize]; // This line still produces two errors
    assert_eq!(val, i);
}
```

So scoping doesn't seem to be the thing influencing the change in behaviour.

Why does separating the code into two loops make the code stop producing the errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the struct's lifetime ends at the last place of use.

In detail, the error message for your original code:

```
error[E0503]: cannot use `plugin.data` because it was mutably borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:29:15
   |
26 |     system.attach_plugin(&mut plugin);
   |                          ----------- borrow of `plugin` occurs here
27 |     for i in 0..255 {
28 |     system.plugin.as_mut().unwrap().write(i as usize, i);
   |     ------------- borrow later used here
29 |     let val = plugin.data[i as usize]; // This line produces two errors
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of borrowed `plugin`
```

It explains clearly that `system` contains a mutable reference to `plugin`. In the for loop, you firstly use `system`, then immutably refer to `plugin` in the next line. Rust doesn't allow mutable and immutable reference at the same time. Note that you are in a loop, so the next iteration still uses `system`, i.e. `system` is alive when `let val = plugin.data[i as usize]` is in execution (at least in the first iteration).

The reason why if you separate `system` and `plugin` operations into two "for" loops it doesn't err, is that after the first "for" loop you don't use `system`, so the compiler decides that `system`'s lifetime ends immediately after the first "for" loop. Then there won't be borrow violations.

The reason why using a scope in one loop doesn't help is that still, you have next iterations of loop, so `system`'s lifetime doesn't end before the next sentence.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `system.attach_plugin(&mut plugin)`, you have given `system` an *exclusive* reference to `plugin`. Therefore `plugin` cannot be used while `system` exists.

The compiling code works because the compiler sees that after the first loop `system` is no longer used. So it can release that exclusive hold on the reference allowing `plugin` to be used again.